# Accented characters of a vCard not displaying in Windows Contacts

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, contacts, vcf-vcard

I am writing a method that allows a user to generate a vCard file based on some information. It works quite well and the user can open the generated file with Microsoft Outlook without any problem (tested on versions 2010 and 2013). But when he wants to open it with Windows Contacts, the accented characters are not well displayed whereas I have set the charset to the different fields to UTF-8.

Here is an example of a generated vCard:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
FN;CHARSET=utf-8:Vandenbergh Cédric
N;CHARSET=utf-8:Vandenbergh;Cédric;;;
TITLE;CHARSET=utf-8:Manager d'entité
END:VCARD
```

And here is what I get when opening it with Windows Contacts:

[image: vCard in Windows Contacts]

Could it be a bug in Windows Contacts (tested under Windows 8.1)? Or am I missing something?

**Edit**

Here is the code I use for a user to download a vCard:

```
Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.Buffer = true;
Context.Response.ContentType = "text/x-vCard; charset=utf-8";
Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=file.vcf");
Context.Response.Write(user.GetVCard()); // Get vCard content
Context.Response.Flush();
Context.Response.End();
```

***Edit 2/10/15***

I still have no idea on how to solve this problem. In my opinion, it could really be a Windows Contacts bug but I cannot find anything on the web to confirm my impression.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you add a "CHARSET=utf-8" parameter doesn't mean the value will be written in UTF-8.  You are probably not setting the character encoding to "UTF-8" when you write the vCard.

Also, note that vCard version 4.0 does not support the "CHARSET" parameter.  The specification states that all vCards MUST be written in UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Michael. I have edited my question by adding the code I use for a user to download a vCard file. As you can see, I have set the character encoding in the "ContentType" property but with no success. I have also tried to use the version 2.1 of vCard Windows Contacts certainly supports but here also without any success. I have seen [in that link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-ecoms/utf-8-vcard-is-unsupported-by-windows-contacts-and/2ce5f5b1-4be4-4ce4-8063-9518323eb32b) someone seems to have the same problem but there is no answer.

Comment: @Opec Is there a way to set the character encoding on the `Context.Response` object?  Something like: `Context.Response.Encoding = "UTF-8"`.  Including the encoding in the ContentType may not be enough.  In other words, it may be writing the vCard in your system's default character encoding, which, on Windows, is **not** UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, it's possible by adding the following line of code: `Context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8`. Unfortunately, nothing changes. I have the impression that it's a Windows Contacts bug. I don't currently see anything else I could do for the characters to be well displayed.